# How to Join two tables with same attributes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables, I want to create a new table with same attribute using the data from two tables.
following is the code im trying

```
/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE NAMES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE GAMES(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE JJ(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name varchar(100));

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(1,'Tom');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(2,'Lucy');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(3,'Frank');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(4,'Jane');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES(5,'Robert');
INSERT INTO GAMES VALUES(7,'Football');
INSERT INTO GAMES VALUES(6,'Rugby');
COMMIT;

/* Display all the records from the table */
SELECT * FROM NAMES;
SELECT * FROM GAMES;
INSERT INTO JJ (Id, Name) VALUES((SELECT * FROM NAMES), (SELECT * FROM GAMES));

SELECT * FROM JJ; 'Error: near line 21: sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1'
```

Comment: which SQL are you using?

Answer (score 2):

this will work for oracle :

```
INSERT INTO JJ (Id, Name)((SELECT * FROM NAMES) union all(SELECT * FROM GAMES));
```

for mysql :

```
   insert into JJ select * from Names union all select * from Games;
```

but as Zaynul said when two primary key matches it will throw an error!!!!

Comment: @RahulKumar its done check it syntactical problems were there!!!!!!!!!!1

Answer (score 0):

the way you trying to merge two table is not better aproach b/c two different table primary key may same which will thrown error in times of 3rd table insertion(duplicate key). i would prefer change your table structure make all three table primary key auto increment and push just name not id

```
INSERT INTO JJ ( Name)
select name from (
SELECT name FROM NAMES
union all
SELECT name FROM GAMES
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest declaring `JJ` as:

```
CREATE TABLE JJ (
    Id integer auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(100)
);

insert into jj (name)
    select name from names union all
    select game from games;
```